# Загрузка без обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

На сайте есть навигационная панель. Когда нажимаешь на какой-то раздел, то моментально переходишь на него, и даже в Chrome не  видно, чтобы страница обновлялась (эмблемка обновления страницы, не изменяется).

Интересно еще то, что URL страницы меняется при навигации по разделам.

Подскажите, что это за технология такая?

Мои варианты:

**1.** AJAX

**2.** RAJAX

**Напишите список вариантов, что это может быть.**

Comment: Сейчас туча разных фрейвфорков, библиотек что бы можно было "написать сайт без перезагрузки страницы". Лучше скиньте ссылку на сайт, тогда можно будет точно ответить...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно даже `pjax` (`pjax` = `pushState` + `ajax`), о чем красноречиво говорит изменение URL страницы. Вот [ссылка на библиотеку](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) от автора pjax Chris Wanstrath.

Вот тут ссылка на [туторал](http://www.littlestreamsoftware.com/labs/learning-pjax/), где довольно подробно показывают, как это делать.

Ну а на самом деле там может быть что угодно, вплоть до Angular, ReactJS и прочего.

Comment: Да вы телепат =)

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Не, скорее здравомыслящей человек. Был задан вопрос - `Напишите список вариантов` - был дан соответствующий ответ, от Vladimir Jucov. За что ему большое спасибо. Интересно, а как вы интерпретировали этот вопрос?)

Comment: @Vladimir Jucov  Вы бы не могли подсказать мне по одному вопросу?http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496032/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B3-%D0%B2-yii2-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-pjax