# Баг в Yii2 или почему странно работает Pjax

Tags: yii2, pjax

Баг в Yii2 или почему странно работает Pjax?

Смотрите:
Обертываем формочку с навигационной панелью в Pjax:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?= NavWidget::widget(['navgen' => ['item' =>[
                                       ['label' => 'button1',  'url' => 'http://yii2/basic/web/index.php?r=site/say'], 
                                       ['label' => 'button2',  'url' => 'http://yii2/basic/web/index.php?r=form/entry'], 
                                       ['label' => 'button3',  'url' => 'http://yii2/basic/web/index.php?r=pjax/pjax'] ,
                                       ['label' => 'button4',  'url' => '#'], 
                                       ['label' => 'button5',  'url' => '#'] 
                                                 ]
                                       ]
                          ]); 
   ?>


<div><?= $content ?></div>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Если переходить по ней, то постоянно будет обновлять favicon сайта. Он будет дергаться, и резать глаза. Чтобы этого избежать, мы должны в конце ссылке, поставить **#**.

Вопрос: Что это такое и с чем это едят?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` — это специальный символ URL, который сообщает браузеру, что последующая часть адреса представляет собой ссылку на HTML элемент с таким id или именованный якорь (named anchor) текущей страницы. Это канонически.

В случае с pjax `#` указывает на обновляемый container.

Как указанно в документации pjax

> Affecting the browser URL
>
> If the server needs to affect the URL which will appear in the browser URL after pjax navigation (like HTTP redirects work for normal requests), it can set the X-PJAX-URL header:

```
   def index
       request.headers['X-PJAX-URL'] = "http://example.com/hello"
   end
```

что-бы не перегружалась страница пользователя (в случае редиректа, к примеру)
в Yii2 это делается вот так:

`Yii::$app->response->getHeaders()->set('X-PJAX-Url',Url::to(['controller/action','id' => $model->id]));`

Comment: Кстати обнаружил одну особенность. Если использовать в одной из страниц ` ActiveForm::begin(); ` с пустым `begin()`,  то есть , без этого ActiveForm::begin([ 'id' => 'login-form']); То при переходе на эту страницу, она обновляется, так-же как  и  при уходе с неё. Вот именно после этого, моргание favicon начинается, и помогает если только нажать на `button4 = #`, или, два раза нажать на другой button, у которого в конце адреса поставлен `#`, кроме  того, который ссылается на страницу с ActiveForm.

Comment: Хорошо написано про использование pjax в Yii2 вот [тут](http://nix-tips.ru/yii2-vnikaem-v-pjax.html)
Кроме того, почитайте офф документацию Yii2 на предмет свойств pjax класса. Обратите внимание на `formSelector`. Я саму форму редко когда оборачиваю в pjax, оборачиваю только то, что надо обновить.

Comment: А оборачиваете ли вы страницу по такой формуле, навигационная панель+данные сайта+подвал -  если нет , то почему?

Comment: Да, я использую layout. Но обновляю только часть из "данные сайта",

Comment: А именно, всю информацию  которая содержится между <body>, оборачиваете ли Вы в  Pjax? И если нет, то почему? Получается не вся страница обвёрнута в Pjax, а только все данные которые расположены между тегом <body>